# Supporting multiple requests - django API backend

Tags: django, api, rest, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building a backend API for a chat app with Django and DRF. It basically handles direct interaction with a MySQL database and also manages other important components like authentication, authorization, and user management.
Our team has built an API microservice for enabling chat on our client mobile app. We're doing this through websockets and rabbitMQ on node.js.

So we've put this up online and are realizing that the Django backend doesn't seem to support the vast requests being sent from the chat API. Running a load test on the Django app shows that it's dropping up to 90% or requests. Adding more servers connected to a load balancer has not improved the situation either.
I suppose this is being bottlenecked by the blocking nature of Django (actually DRF in particular). But it's just my hunch and I'm not really sure as to what the problem really is.

Does anyone have advice on how to improve performance for the Django API.

Comment: Have you identified the slow parts of your application? Django projects can handle __huge__ loads if deployed correctly. As an example I believe instagram is/was a Django application

Comment: This is most likely an infrastructure issue (deployment environment configuration, or something lower-level) more than a Django issue. As a first point of investigation, how do you know that the requests are being dropped? Are the clients able to establish the TCP connections to your web server in the first place? What is your deployment setup like, and how are the web servers configured in the individual app servers you're putting up behind the load balancer?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Iain. Yes, I have found a few culprits. So we're doing some things like read receipts for messages. For 2 users in a conversation, each client makes continuous requests to the Django API to verify whether the other party has read the message. And this happens when the user (client) is online. There are 2 other similar components working like this as well. I'm also trying to quantify this with my teammate so I understand how many requests as made per second per user.

Comment: Thank you Ramones. I think you're right - it's fundamentally this. 

This was my setup config:
- I'm running gunicorn in a supervisor task. This is running 7 workers and bound to a unix domain socket.
- Then I set my upstream app server in Nginx to this socket 

- I'm currently running one server (to test) connected to a load balancer on Digital Ocean. I spin up copies of this server sometimes but keep it to 1, for now, to save on costs since we're still in development. 
**Also new to containerization and all that stuff so I want to get it right before permanently adding more servers

Comment: @DJRamones About how I figured the requests are being dropped: They yielded 503 error responses. We couldn't tell at the time whether this was from the Django API or the database. I also ran a load test with [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) and noticed about 90% of requests where being dropped when I fired 1K+ requests per second.

Comment: @IainShelvington @DJRamones

I realized that my Gunicorn config meant that I could only handle 7 requests... at a given time...whilst queueing the rest. :-\

Also, connections to the database were not persisting. So in my django settings, I set [CONN_MAX_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#conn-max-age) to None to enforce persistent connections per worker.
Then I used gevent with gunicorn to implement some concurrency: `worker-class=gevent and --worker-connection=1000`
....

Comment: Consequently, the app runs much smoother now. But, there are still a few errors in messaging + read receipts. I'd really appreciate your recommendations on how best to improve performance. I'm rather new to doing concurrency and async.
So far, I've done a little reading to realize that I could potentially benefit from using celery in Django. I've also noticed that Django 3.0+ now has some asyncio support built in....however, DRF doesn't so I think that's quite a handicap. 

Can you advise on suggest paths to take for performance enhancements?

Comment: I don't think using Celery will address what should be your main goal, which is minimizing the average time it takes to complete serving each request. Even the default gunicorn config (that uses sync workers and queues requests when the workers are all occupied) shouldn't cause errors (as in dropped requests) if the average response time is efficient enough. Generally I suggest focusing on two things: (1) making sure your Django views are database-efficient, and (2) ensure you're not hitting any environment configuration constraints.

Comment: About environment configuration constraints: your earlier issue with 90% failed requests on 1K requests/sec (I presume that means 1K concurrent connections, the `-c` flag in `loadtest`) reminds me of when I hit the default `somaxconn` value of 128 in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier. This value meant that the server could only process 128 connections out of the 500 concurrent connections I tried to load-test it with at first; the rest were dropped and the corresponding requests failed. You should watch out for and investigate limits like this.